# Fix height of frametitle independent of content

Tags: beamer, vertical-alignment

I'm using a custom `beamer` theme from my university. The `frametitle` height depends on whether any characters extend below the baseline. A `frametitle` named "example" is higher than a title named "test". This leads to jumping blocks when the content blocks are top-aligned.

The `frametitle` is defined as follows:

```
%frametitle

\setbeamertemplate{frametitle}
{
\vspace{2mm} \hspace*{-4mm}
\vbox{\hsize=10cm\bfseries\insertframetitle}

\begin{textblock*}{15mm}(110mm,4mm)
\includegraphics[width=14mm]{\logo} 
\end{textblock*}

\begin{textblock*}{1.5mm}(1mm,1mm)
\begin{pgfpicture}{0mm}{0mm}{1.5mm}{9mm}
    \color{green100}
    \pgfpathrectangle{\pgfpoint{0mm}{0mm}}{\pgfpoint{1.5mm}{9mm}}
    \pgfusepath{fill}
\end{pgfpicture}%
\end{textblock*}

}
```

Presentation example of jumping blocks:

```
\documentclass[t]{beamer}

\usetheme{jumping-theme}
\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
 \frametitle{test}
 \begin{block}{test}
  t
 \end{block}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
 \frametitle{Example}
 \begin{block}{example}
  e
 \end{block}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Is there any way to fix the `frametitle` height? I thought the `\vbox` with height parameter would take care of this, but it doesn't.

Comment: This should fix it: replace `\insertframetitle` with `\strut\insertframetitle`.

Comment: Possibly also `\strut` at the end

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Replace

```
\vbox{\hsize=10cm\bfseries\insertframetitle}
```

with

```
\vbox{\hsize=10cm\bfseries\strut\insertframetitle\strut}
```